# Why are there no antimatter-antimatter collisions in CERN?

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter, protons, large-hadron-collider

The labs at CERN create anti-Protons, and have collided them with Protons. Anti-Hydrogen is used to study matter-antimatter asymmetry.

Were there any attempts to collide anti-Protons with anti-Protons? It seems like a direct way to study this asymmetry, and there is ample reference measurements from Proton-Proton collisions. If not, is this due to lack of motivation, or just a practical issue?

Comment: Making a high current anti-proton beam is hard. It's a technical/economic choice to make two counter-rotating proton beams instead. You can find the technical documentation for LHC on the CERN document server: https://cds.cern.ch/?ln=en. There should be design documents for LHC which detail the decision making process for the chosen design.

Comment: reading this will help understand the difficulties with antiprotons https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Proton%E2%80%93Antiproton_Synchrotron